# Do Sauna belts really help in losing belly, hips, and buttocks fat?

Tags: weight-loss, body-fat

Do Sauna belts really help in losing belly, hips, and buttocks fat? How effective are they? Are there any side effects associated in using it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sauna belts are yet another fad that the weight loss industry seems to perpetuate as a sure fire way to lose weight.  Unfortunately, there’s no scientific evidence that shows they are effective in reducing body fat.  They can, however, reduce water weight.

> Because they produce excessive perspiration, sauna belts are supposed
>   to reduce water weight more effectively than fat tissue. Because the
>   product does not provide any resistance or strain against the body, it
>   is incapable of burning a significant amount of calories. So, while
>   noticeable fat loss is not realistic, a person can effectively lose a
>   few pounds through water loss. ([Livestrong.com](http://www.livestrong.com/article/187012-what-are-the-benefits-of-a-sauna-belt/))

And, more importantly, Sauna belts seem to rely on the concept of “spot reducing”.  “Spot reducing” is widely accepted as a myth because targeting specific areas of the body for weight loss is not possible.

As for side effects, they’re not all bad.  Since sauna belts increase heat at the site they are worn, they can be used as a therapy modality for pain.

> Heat application can effectively reduce pain as it warms the muscles,
>   making them more flexible and relaxed which allows for better blood
>   flow. Since sauna belts provide a constant supply of heat, some people
>   wear them for hassle-free relief of back pain. ([Livestrong.com](http://www.livestrong.com/article/187012-what-are-the-benefits-of-a-sauna-belt/))

On the negative side, the following are the more [common effects](http://watchfit.com/weight-loss/will-i-lose-weight-with-a-sauna-belt/#)…

> - Can cause chafing, acne, or heat rash
> - Can be uncomfortable
> - Increases risk of heat-related illness
> - Overexposure to belt can cause dehydration
> - Can cause electrolyte imbalance which may cause cramping
> - Does not provide long-term results

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, no (non-surgical, obviously) way is known to reduce fat *locally*.

The only fat reduction tool in existence remains a combination of increased energy output and reduced input - AKA exercising and not eating too much. Everything else is dishonest marketing.